# Understanding ClientContext.Load's Parameters

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, lambda

I have some code which makes calls to a SharePoint Managed Metadata Service that starts off like this :

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://mysharepointsite/")
    { AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default};

var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
var termStore = taxonomySession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
```

which I have no problem with. However, after this we have :

```
clientContext.Load(termStore,
        store => store.Name,
        store => store.Groups.Include(
            group => group.Name,
            group => group.TermSets.Include(
                termSet => termSet.Name,
                termSet => termSet.Terms.Include(
                    term => term.Name)
            )
        )
);
```

Can anyone please help me understand what is going on here?

- At first I thought this was some kind of LINQ query, but then I would expect the class to have the line `using System.Linq;`, which it does not.
- I just noticed that in Visual Studio there is some IntelliSense which says the call is structured like this :  `void ClientruntimeContext.Load<T>(T clientObject, params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, object>>[] retrievals)` - which makes it seem like it is using Linq in some way
- I understand that the code is in some way "loading" the termstore data in the managed metadata service from the given sharepoint site, but I don't quite understand what exactly that syntax is doing.
- I got the code sample from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn904534.aspx), and it does exactly what I want it to do but I would feel a lot more comfortable if I actually understood that syntax!
- [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536388.aspx) was also not particularly helpful, as it just defines `Load()`s parameters as `<T>`, which could be anything!

Any advice or recommended reading is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [`ClientRuntimeContext.Load<T>` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536388(v=office.14).aspx)

The second parameter of this method specifies what properties of target client object (first parameter) should be retrieved using lambda expressions.

**Examples**

In the following query, all the properties except *collection* properties such as [`TermStore.Groups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.termstore.groups.aspx) of [`TermStore` client object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.termstore.aspx) will be retrieved

```
ctx.Load(termStore);
```

In the next query only the  explicitly specified list of properties (`TermStore.Name`, `TermStore.Groups`) will be retrieved for [`TermStore` client object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.termstore.aspx):

```
ctx.Load(termStore, store => store.Name, store => store.Groups);
```

The next question arise, how to specify what properties of collection client object to retrieve, [`Include<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, \[\])` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee544003(v=office.14).aspx) method comes to the rescue here.

## [`Include<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, \[\])` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee544003(v=office.14).aspx)

This method is used to limit what properties are returned from a collection of objects ( for performance purposes)

**Example**

The following expression

```
ctx.Load(termStore, store => store.Groups.Include( g => g.Name));
```

tells to construct the query to return [`TermStore` client object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.termstore.aspx) which includes `TermStore.Groups` property but not the default properties of `Group` client object, only `Group.Name` property.